# lazy line painter as a pre-loader

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, preload, preloader

I have an animated SVG using lazy line painter that I would like to use as a pre-loader. How can I review the page content (with a transition or a simple fade-in) after the line animation is completed?

**So the concept is this: on landing LOAD SVG animation when COMPLETE transition into page content.**

```
    <!-- Include lazylinepainter -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ lazy-line-painter@1.9.4/lib/lazy-line-painter-1.9.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.15.0/d3.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          (function(){

            document.onreadystatechange = () => {

              if (document.readyState === 'complete') {


                let el = document.querySelector('#markin2');
                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":2.2,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#fff"});
                myAnimation.paint();
              }
            }

          })();

        </script>

  <svg version="1.1" id="markin2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="314.094px" height="314.765px" viewBox="0 0 314.094 314.765" enable-background="new 0 0 314.094 314.765" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<circle fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="157.828" cy="157.404" r="150.813" data-llp-id="markin2-0" data-llp-duration="2920" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="1"  data-llp-stroke-join="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
<path id="#markin2" class=".markin2" fill="none" values="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M18.482,132.273
    c1.019-4.147,1.774-8.38,3.099-12.427c7.988-24.405,24.611-39.774,49.798-44.317c26.582-4.795,47.878,5.064,64.031,26.525
    c2.094,2.782,2.112,4.714-0.499,7.183c-3.496,3.306-6.592,7.035-10.095,10.837c-2.364-3.506-4.425-7.039-6.94-10.211
    C104.843,93.427,81.91,88.297,62.884,97.426c-18.967,9.102-29.097,30.539-24.289,51.399c4.649,20.172,22.977,34.573,43.973,34.571
    c13.572-0.002,24.751-5.104,33.906-15.18c22.505-24.771,44.815-49.735,67.885-73.971c17.361-18.239,39.164-24.295,63.441-17.369
    c24.221,6.91,39.282,23.516,45.102,48.006c3.184,13.398,1.887,26.967-2.008,39.987c-1.322,4.422-5.715,7.985-8.899,11.78
    c-10.94,13.035-24.349,21.988-41.47,24.67c-19.018,2.979-35.86-2.006-50.829-13.86c-1.162-0.92-2.304-1.863-4.361-3.533
    c0,2.48-0.004,4.178,0,5.873c0.045,22.324,0.009,44.646,0.213,66.967c0.037,3.956-0.771,7.102-3.877,9.674
    c-1.653,1.37-3.243,2.961-4.409,4.748c-2.552,3.912-5.974,4.865-10.668,3.637c0-6.688,0.01-13.473-0.003-20.258
    c-0.041-22.488,0.024-44.979-0.227-67.465c-0.056-4.814,1.073-8.443,4.622-11.914c6.039-5.908,11.509-12.398,17.593-19.056
    c4.06,8.205,9.36,14.85,16.678,19.736c15.507,10.355,35.698,10.172,51.128-0.49c15.202-10.506,22.338-29.406,18.086-47.903
    c-3.979-17.298-19.188-31.573-37.106-33.975c-15.415-2.066-29.11,2.093-39.841,13.781c-21.17,23.057-42.371,46.092-63.192,69.461
    c-14.497,16.271-31.743,25.988-53.992,25.404c-30.517-0.799-56.945-24.744-60.94-55.143c-0.123-0.934-0.602-1.821-0.915-2.73
    C18.482,140.272,18.482,136.272,18.482,132.273z" data-llp-id="markin2-1" data-llp-duration="2920" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="1" data-llp-stroke-join="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
            background: #000;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }

            #markin2 {
              width: 40vw;
              height: 40vh;
              position: relative;
              overflow: visible;
            }

            .markin2 {
  animation: stroke_fill 4s linear forwards, changeColor 2s, forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 1538.2169189453125px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
@keyframes stroke_fill {

  0% {
    fill: white;
  }
  50% {
    fill: white;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes changeColor {
        from{ fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
        to{ fill: rgba(0,0,0,1)}
      }
```

Here is the SVG animation example:

https://codepen.io/cpawl/pen/zYvEqYq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lazy Line Painter library has some custom events built in to which you can listen. Such as the `complete` event whenever you animation has been completed. Whenever that event is called, hide the SVG.

In the example below I've added this event listener but also wrapped your animation in a Promise. This way you can wait for it to finish and then do something. And also another Promise which listens for the `load` event on the document. So that this is an actual page loader and the SVG would not disappear before the page would be loaded.

In your HTML first load the SVG and then the JS you see below here. Inside the `then` callback function either delete your SVG, or set a class to the body which hides the class. Anyway you see fit.

```css
body,
html {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#markin2 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.markin2 {
  animation: stroke_fill 4s linear forwards, changeColor 2s, forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 1538.2169189453125px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

@keyframes stroke_fill {
  0% {
    fill: white;
  }
  50% {
    fill: white;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}

.hsvg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 2000ms ease-in-out;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
}

body.is-loaded .hsvg {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.main-content {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazy-line-painter@1.9.6/lib/lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include lazylinepainter -->
<div class="hsvg">
  <svg version="1.1" id="markin2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="314.094px" height="314.765px" viewBox="0 0 314.094 314.765" enable-background="new 0 0 314.094 314.765" xml:space="preserve"
    data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<circle fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="157.828" cy="157.404" r="150.813" data-llp-id="markin2-0" data-llp-duration="2920" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="1"  data-llp-stroke-join="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
<path id="#markin2" class=".markin2" fill="none" values="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M18.482,132.273
    c1.019-4.147,1.774-8.38,3.099-12.427c7.988-24.405,24.611-39.774,49.798-44.317c26.582-4.795,47.878,5.064,64.031,26.525
    c2.094,2.782,2.112,4.714-0.499,7.183c-3.496,3.306-6.592,7.035-10.095,10.837c-2.364-3.506-4.425-7.039-6.94-10.211
    C104.843,93.427,81.91,88.297,62.884,97.426c-18.967,9.102-29.097,30.539-24.289,51.399c4.649,20.172,22.977,34.573,43.973,34.571
    c13.572-0.002,24.751-5.104,33.906-15.18c22.505-24.771,44.815-49.735,67.885-73.971c17.361-18.239,39.164-24.295,63.441-17.369
    c24.221,6.91,39.282,23.516,45.102,48.006c3.184,13.398,1.887,26.967-2.008,39.987c-1.322,4.422-5.715,7.985-8.899,11.78
    c-10.94,13.035-24.349,21.988-41.47,24.67c-19.018,2.979-35.86-2.006-50.829-13.86c-1.162-0.92-2.304-1.863-4.361-3.533
    c0,2.48-0.004,4.178,0,5.873c0.045,22.324,0.009,44.646,0.213,66.967c0.037,3.956-0.771,7.102-3.877,9.674
    c-1.653,1.37-3.243,2.961-4.409,4.748c-2.552,3.912-5.974,4.865-10.668,3.637c0-6.688,0.01-13.473-0.003-20.258
    c-0.041-22.488,0.024-44.979-0.227-67.465c-0.056-4.814,1.073-8.443,4.622-11.914c6.039-5.908,11.509-12.398,17.593-19.056
    c4.06,8.205,9.36,14.85,16.678,19.736c15.507,10.355,35.698,10.172,51.128-0.49c15.202-10.506,22.338-29.406,18.086-47.903
    c-3.979-17.298-19.188-31.573-37.106-33.975c-15.415-2.066-29.11,2.093-39.841,13.781c-21.17,23.057-42.371,46.092-63.192,69.461
    c-14.497,16.271-31.743,25.988-53.992,25.404c-30.517-0.799-56.945-24.744-60.94-55.143c-0.123-0.934-0.602-1.821-0.915-2.73
    C18.482,140.272,18.482,136.272,18.482,132.273z" data-llp-id="markin2-1" data-llp-duration="2920" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="1" data-llp-stroke-join="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
</svg>
</div>

<script>
  const pageLoad = new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener('load', resolve);
  });

  const animationLoad = new Promise(resolve => {
    let el = document.querySelector('#markin2');
    let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {
      "ease": "easeLinear",
      "strokeWidth": 2.2,
      "strokeOpacity": 1,
      "strokeColor": "#fff"
    });
    myAnimation.paint();
    myAnimation.on('complete', resolve);
  });

  Promise.all([pageLoad, animationLoad]).then(function() {
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded');
    console.log('Load event fired and animation done');
  });
</script>

<div class="main-content">
  <h1>IS THIS THING ON?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am not sure I completely understand. Would it be possible for you to show an example?

Comment: Sure, I've added a snippet in which you can try it out.

Comment: Nice! So how would I display loaded content after the animation is complete in the "is-loaded" body class?

Comment: With CSS. Without the `.is-loaded` class the SVG should be showing and with the class it should be hidden, like in the example above.

Comment: Right. I added styles to the class `.is-loaded ` with a DIV `.main-content` and it displays prior to the animation fade. Plus while hidden is still is effecting the SVG loaders page position

Comment: Just show your main content by default and create an overlay with the SVG. Wrap the SVG in a `div` and give it `position: fixed`, stretch it out over the screen, give it a black background color and make sure the `z-index` is high enough. Then fade out the div with your SVG in it and it will reveal the content underneath. The main content and the SVG won't interfere with each other this way.

Comment: I got it working now (thanks) but I am still having issues that the content loads prior to the SVG fading out.

Comment: Create a new question in SO for this, create an example in which we can see what you see and send the link here. I'll take a look.

Comment: Here is an example - I'll create a new question if need be but hopefully this will be enough https://codepen.io/cpawl/pen/KKdopMQ

Comment: I've updated the snippet above with the codepen code you provided. Pay close attention to the CSS. And to have optimal performance place your SVG, CSS (in a `<style>` tag) and JS (in a `<script>` tag, but not as a file, but as JS in HTML) as high up in your `<body>`. This is because the document is loaded from top to bottom, so your SVG will be the first thing loaded and the rest can load behind the SVG and wait for the `load` event.